# Is this simple probability experiment mathematically valid?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose I design an experiment where  a fair coin is tossed twice. Result of each toss is noted, but if two heads or two tails show, then this is not accepted and thus not noted. Would then the samples space simply consist of 2 elements, i.e. $\{HT, TH\}$ ? Is this an acceptable probability experiment?

Edit: my understanding says no, since all outcomes must be recorded by definition, right?

Another edit. Generally, if one performs some experiment and certain results are discarded / not accepted, are they still technically outcomes? Or how does one then denote the relevant sample space?

Comment: Well...technically you could have an infinite sequence in which neither $HT$ nor $TH$ ever occur.  Granted that has probability $0$ but it is still a possible event.

Comment: So are you saying that sample space should be something like $\{HT, TH, \{\} \}$ ,  i.e. include an empty set as well, hence technically it will consist of 3 elements? @lulu

Comment: "*not accepted and not noted*"  What happens after 'not noting' something?  Do you try again (*and again etc...*) until you get a result?  Or do you just leave the spot on the paper blank where you would have otherwise written a result and stop there, not flipping anything more?

Comment: If your experimental setup includes the discard, and you define the outcome of the experiment as what gets written on the paper or otherwise somehow carefully specify that an outcome is restricted to those nondiscarded results then yes. You are free to set up experiments and define what you consider an outcome however you please. Probability theory doesn’t have rules on what experiments can and can’t be.

Comment: Ah yes, ok, you are saying we need to be more precise. If we keep trying ad infinitum, then we have $\{HT, TH, \{\} \}$, right?  And in case we stop immediately, then it is indeed $\{HT, TH\}$ ? @JMoravitz

Comment: It really kind of depends on you... but I would have phrased them both as $\{HT,TH,\text{n/a}\}$ with the understanding that in the ad infinitum case we have $\Pr(\{HT\})=\Pr(\{TH\})=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\Pr(\{\text{n/a}\})=0$ while in the second case $\Pr(\{HT\})=\Pr(\{TH\})=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\Pr(\{\text{n/a}\})=\frac{1}{2}$.  You could talk about conditional probabilities $\Pr(X\mid \{HT,TH\})$ which would be what you are hoping for with the two-element "(*restricted*) sample space"

Comment: Thanks @JMoravitz

Comment: The empty set is always a “possible” event. Even for a single coin flip, it could land on its side or quantum teleport elsewhere in the multiverse. Discarding low probability physical outcomes is typical. Discarding high probability outcomes may feel strange, but again, you have freedom to define the experiment.

Comment: The probability that you eventually observe a valid event is $1$. You can even simulate this experiment with a single coin (the other must exhibit the opposite result). It does not matter how many irrelevant events would occur.

Comment: @jdods the empty set is indeed a possible *event* however it is not a possible *outcome*.  Reworded... the empty set is always a *subset* of a set, but it is not necessarily always an *element* of a set.  Do not confuse the sample space, the set consisting of all outcomes, with the probability space... the set consisting of all events (*which are themselves sets of outcomes*).

Comment: This is an important clarification! Using $\{\}$ as representing a probability zero outcome is not wrong, per se, but it's just not advisable. Of course, that "empty set notation" is now not representing the empty set event. It's just poorly-chosen notation for a particular outcome.